# React native wkwebview cookie bug

Tags: ios, cookies, react-native, wkwebview

I'm working to build a react native app that's essentially a webview. For the ios version I am using WKWebView instead of the normal webview for a variety of reasons, but WKWebView does not seem to be persisting my cookies after the initial load. I'm using react-native-cookie-manager and react-native-wkwebview-reborn, but the issue is not with those modules.

I inspect `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` and see that the request upon navigation is not receiving the desired cookies. I checked the `sharedHTTPCookieStorage` and saw the cookies I wanted set properly. When I login and immediately close the app, the cookie works for navigation. When I login and try to navigate without resetting the app, the cookie is not persisted through navigation.

Comment: Seems to be related to an issue with timing on the sync between wkwebsitedata store and nshttpcookiestorage. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50057

Comment: did you get this to work?